# Matlab Assigning 1D slice of 3D array

Tags: matlab

How do I assign 1 dimensional slices in a 3d array in MATLAB?

I have a logical 2d array named 'CD' which corresponds to the pixels of a 3-D image matrix (RGB format) that I would like to set.

```
CD = any(d, 3);
CDM(CD) = 255;
```

So in this case, 'CDM' is a 3d matrix containing R,G,B values for every pixel (e.g. it's a 771x457x3 matrix).

The above code works.  It generates an image of red pixels I want them.

But suppose now that I want to generate, say, green or cyan pixels?  How do I access the second and third "layers" (the green and blue values) of 'CDM'?  I tried assigning

```
CDM(CD) = [0 255 255];
```

but this returns the error

```
In an assignment  A(:) = B, the number of elements in A and B must be the same.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to modify each channel with a 2D array like that, you need to grab each channel (as a 2D array), then use the 2D logical array to replace the pixels you want with the desired value and then assign it back into the array.

```
green = CDM(:,:,2);
green(CD) = 255;
CDM(:,:,2) = green;
```

Alternately, you could do something like the following to vectorize the problem.

```
replace_color = [0 255 255];
CDM = bsxfun(@times, ~CD, CDM) + bsxfun(@times, CD, reshape(replace_color, [1 1 3]))
```

**Explanation**

First we use `bsxfun` to perform dimension broadcasting and multiply every RGB pixel within `CDM` with the inverse (`~`) of the logical matrix. This sets all of the pixels that are `1` in `CD` to `0` and leaves all other pixels as their original value (since they are multiplied by `1`).

```
bsxfun(@times, ~CD, CDM)
```

We then multiply `CD` by the new color (reshaped to be a 1 x 1 x 3 array) to produce an M x N x 3 array where each RGB vector where `CD` was `1` is the desired RGB value and all other values are `0`.

```
bsxfun(@times, CD, reshape(replace_color, [1 1 3]))
```

We then add these two together to keep the RGB value wherever `CD` was `0` and replace the RGB value with the new value wherever `CD` was `1`.

If you're on R2016b or later, you can remove `bsxfun` and the solution is simplified to:

```
CDM = (~CD .* CDM) + (CD .* reshape(replace_color, [1 1 3]));
```

Comment: All three solutions worked!  Really great answers, thanks.

Comment: What is different in R2016 SO you can "remove `bsxfun`"?

Comment: 2016 does automatic expansion of singleton dimensions for array operations (?), which is what `bsxfun` does.

Comment: @Floris There are a lot of improvements, but one of the most prominent ones is automatic broadcasting of singleton dimensions.... so yes, you can remove `bsxfun` and MathWorks recommends you do that because it will be faster, more easier to read and more efficient.